# Linux compilation in docker Ubuntu 16.04 - no dependence files created

Tags: linux, docker, compilation, arm

I compile Linux with following procedure:
[Compulab Imx7 Arm cross compilation procedure](http://mediawiki.compulab.com/w/index.php5?title=CL-SOM-iMX7:_Linux:_Kernel&oldid=3068)

Now I try to move this compilation to run from docker Ubuntu 16.04. Everything works fine except modules dependencies files, that are not created in docker:

```
modules.alias
modules.alias.bin
modules.builtin.bin
modules.dep
modules.dep.bin
modules.devname
modules.softdep
modules.symbols
modules.symbols.bin
```

But following files are created:

```
modules.builtin
modules.order
```

I keep same compilation procedure in docker like usual.
I checked compilation logs, their are very similar.
What am I doing wrong? What should I check first for investigation?

Upd:
for now I found from the Linux Make file that environment is initiated with variable

```
DEPMOD = /sbin/depmod
```

and condition

```
if ! test -e "$DEPMOD"; then
    exit 0
fi
```

fails.
Does it mean that some problem is in docker?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 docker doesn't have depmod utility.
Checked also for Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu 14.04 do have depmod utility.
One should install kmod by himself